# Create variation hierarchies - job completes but does nothing

Tags: 2010, variations, owstimer

This is something I have done many times before on my current VM, and even using the same Web Application, though with different site collections. The steps I am following are:

1) Create a new site collection at the root of the web app. It is the only site collection existing at the time.

2) Go to the newly created site collection settings and enable the Server Publishing Infrastructure feature.

3) Go to the site features and enable Server Publishing feature.

4) Create variation root as /

5) Create variation labels for en-GB (Source) and fr-FR

6) Click 'create hieararchies'

7) Go to Central Admin, find the scheduled job to create hierarchies and 'Run now'

The job runs and completes immediately. In the time job history section there are four new entries for create hierarchies, all have succeeded and all have a duration of 00:00:00

I checked in ULS logs and the job starts, 7 work items are processed, no errors are shown and nothing happens.

The hierarchies are not created. When I check in the variation settings nothing has changed, no hierarchies have been created. There are no variation sites at /en or /fr.

I have selected to create hierarchies and run the timer job several times to no avail. Has anybody experienced this and have any idea what is causing the job to complete without creating the hierarchies?

Comment: I run into the same problem today. Does anyone have already a solution for that?
Thanks!

Comment: Same here!  No idea.

Comment: I find it discouraging that this question is asked on here over and over and there are zero answers across all of them. I still have this question and posting yet another one seems pointless. Can we get an answer to this? Did you eve figure out the cause?

Comment: I found using SharePoint 2010 generally quite discouraging - but that was over 5 years ago. I don't remember if/how I fixed this exactly but I do know that after much messing around with variations we basically sacked them off, wrote our own localisation component that allowed for more sensible translation management and took control of creating all sites, subsites, content types, fields etc programmatically which solved most problems. I thought SharePoint worked better these days?